# asp.net jquery trigger c# function on click at modal form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get data from modal form to parent form but i couldnt make it out. I am creating jquery modal form with webusercontrol and showing data in gridview. I want to get selected rows and add it on grid in my parent form. 
I am creating this with this code my dialog form

```
function dialogAc(ID1) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("/faturaIrsaliye/FaturaKaydet.aspx/abc") %>',
        data: "{ID1:'" + ID1 + "' }",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#IrsaliyeDetay").append(msg.d);
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
    ID11 = ID1;
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
}
```

and this is my method to create.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string abc(String ID1)
        {
            string sonuc = "";
            Page p = new Page();
            UserControl u =  (UserControl)p.LoadControl("~/faturaIrsaliye/WebUserControl1.ascx");
            WebUserControl1 kk = (u as WebUserControl1);
            kk.irsaliyeBaslikID = ID1.toInt();
            p.Controls.Add(u);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(p, sw, false);
            sonuc = sw.ToString();
            sw.Close();
            return sonuc;
        }
```

everythings is fine until now. 
This last code is not triggers my other method. I am getting 404 not found error.

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Select",
            click: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("/faturaIrsaliye/WebUserControl1.ascx/abc") %>',
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#sonuc').html(result.d);
                        alert("clicked");
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
                    }
                });
            },
        }, {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                //window.location.reload(true);
                return false;

            }
        }

        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ResolveUrl requires a relative URL so something like

```
ResolveUrl("~/faturaIrsaliye/WebUserControl1.ascx/abc")
```

Comment: i did try that before but it didnt work. I found the problem. If the method i call in the aspx file it works but if it is in ascx file it returns 404 not found error.